# windows command set variable to grep output

Tags: windows, shell

Status: Noobie
Desired: in Windows command set a variable to grep output

I've done some looking around, and apparently the following strategy should work. But although the first grep output echoed to screen gives the correct output 20 16 21 16 16 as the file patterns.txt is looped through, the variable myvar is reported as always 16, even though I'm deleting tmpfile in each loop.

```
ECHO OFF
For /f %%a in (patterns.txt) do (
  grep -E --count %%a Winter2015.tex 
  grep -E --count %%a Winter2015.tex > tmpfile
  set /p myvar= < tmpfile
  del tmpfile
  echo %myvar%
)
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delay the expansion of variables by adding:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

And using ! around your variables instead of %:

```
echo !myvar!
```

See [this](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).